# Mankind VS Humankind- videogame title

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I know it has been asked here before and from my understanding `mankind` might sound a sexist choice over `humankind`... but it seems there are different subtle interpretations of the terms. At this point I wanted to be very specific asking what do you think about these two words as part of a video game title?

1. Does `humankind` sound too "old-ish"?
2. Does `mankind` sound sexist?
   and in case... could those two words be substituted by just `humanity`?

Comment: There is no objective scale by which something may be deemed old-fashioned or sexist-sounding, and the suitability of names is moreover fundamentally subjective. Requests for opinions, however, are explicitly off-topic everywhere on Stack Exchange. Please review the site [tour] and [help] to see if you can reword.

Comment: I can't understand the downvote actually. This is a request for an opinion about a word choice... so why it should be downvoted and why it's not in line with Stack Exchange?! and the fact that I've added the context "video game title" it's because I think it might be useful to better understand my request.

Answer (score 2):

Mankind can refer to all human beings, male and female, usually in the sense of social or conscious beings. Although people generally consider it less sexist than man (that is also refer to male and female), it is usually better to use a different expression, such as `human beings` (with a plural verb) or `humankind` (with a singular verb):

*`Human beings` have always dreamt of happiness and of a perfect world. or `Humankind` has always dreamt of happiness … (preferred to Mankind has always dreamt …)*

Quoting from this [link](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/mankind-vs-humankind/)

> `Mankind` has been used to refer collectively to humans since the
>   Middle Ages. (`Humankind`, by the way, is younger but also dates back
>   hundreds of years.)

Quoting from this [other link](https://io9.gizmodo.com/5962243/think-twice-before-using-mankind-to-mean-all-humanity-say-scholars) it shows as well a chart tracking the popularity of the words "mankind" and "humanity" in Google's massive text corpus.

> Humanity is more common than mankind in
>   recent English usage, and that mankind is coming to be used less
>   frequently than it previously was, but that mankind remains not
>   particularly rare. The trends in the use of these two words would be
>   well worth watching over the coming years. It may well be the case
>   that a more decisive shift away from using mankind could be in
>   progress, but this would need some careful corpus-based study to
>   confirm.

Comment: +1 for not using Wikipedia as a reference